# PHP Mysql update multiple columns with multiple row values by single query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update rows in mysql, but I have to use a "for" loop for multiple update queries, which have multiple values in each query. The queries are like the following:

```
update table set column1='100',column2='140,column3='150' where id =1
update table set column1='120',column2='145,column3='154' where id =2
update table set column1='141',column2='148,column3='155' where id =3
```

I am using a "for" loop to run multiple queries with different id's, I want to run a single query to update all rows, but not by using "case". Is that possible?

Comment: As the rows and data do not seem to be related, I would probably prepare a query once and execute it multiple times with different data sets.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674737/mysql-update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-in-one-query

Comment: Also you can issue multiple commands ina single batch, that means if you are creatting your script on the fly (and avoiding SQL injects attacks) you can prepare a single script with many updates as you need

Comment: Sorry, i have multiple values for multiple rows. The column name is static, but values are dynamic. 
update table set column1='100',column2='140,column3='150' where id =1 
update table set column1='120',column2='145,column3='154' where id =2 update table set column1='141',column2='148,column3='155' where id =3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use loop for generating dynamic query.
please have a look.
This might be helpful to you.

```
$data[] = array("column1"=>100, "column2"=>140, "column3"=>150, "id"=>1 );
$data[] = array("column1"=>120, "column2"=>145, "column3"=>154, "id"=>2 );
$data[] = array("column1"=>142, "column2"=>148, "column3"=>155, "id"=>3 );

foreach($data as $dat){
    $query = "UPDATE table SET column1=".$dat['column1'].", column2=".$dat['column2'].", column3=".$da['column2']." WHERE id=".$dat['id'];
    echo $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you put the WHERE clause if you wanna update all the ID's? If you don't wanna update all the ID's you will have to do it in a for loop.

```
UPDATE tableName SET column1 = '100', column2 = '140', column3 = '150'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use WHERE IN(...) for this. 
Eg:

```
update table set column1='100',column2='140,column3='150' where id IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: The values are not the same, check the question (okay, the formatting does not help...).

Comment: Sorry, i have multiple values for multiple rows. The column name is static, but values are dynamic. 
update table set column1='100',column2='140,column3='150' where id =1
update table set column1='120',column2='145,column3='154' where id =2 
update table set column1='141',column2='148,column3='155' where id =3

Comment: If you have "multiple" values. then you have to use "multiple" queries since php's mysql_query() supports only one "write" query at a time.