# How to update multiple rows in MySQL by one line?

Tags: mysql

I have PHP array with data.
Now, i'm using a cycle like this:

```
$updArray = array(1=>11,2=>12,3=>13);
foreach($updArray as $id=>$value)
{
    $query = "UPDATE table1 SET column1='$value' WHERE cart_id = '$id'";
    mysql_query($query,$link);
}
```

I think, if array contains thousands rows, it would be slow.
Is there a way to update MySQL table (apply my data from array) without cycle and updating every row?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL - UPDATE multiple rows with different values in one query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674737/mysql-update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-in-one-query)

Comment: Yes. For small datasets you might use IN(). For larger you might store the update information in a separate file and join it the table to be updated

Answer (score 1):

You can try building a single update with a CASE statement, like so:

```
UPDATE table1
    SET column1 = CASE
        WHEN cart_id = 1 THEN 11
        WHEN cart_id = 2 THEN 12
        ...
        ELSE cart_id = cart_id
    END
```

Comment: No. I have thousands rows, i do not want to write WHEN so many.

Comment: @Piter you don't write. Your scripts will build the request using string and arrays using a loop

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO students 
(id, score1, score2)
VALUES 
    (1, 5, 8),
    (2, 10, 8),
    (3, 8, 3),
    (4, 10, 7)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    score1 = VALUES(score1),
score2 = VALUES(score2);
```