# update a table with an array just with one query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

[image]

I receive an array like this:

```
 $data = array(
   array('m_id'=>1,'d_id'=>101,'available'=>0),
   array('m_id'=>1,'d_id'=>102,'available'=>1),
   array('m_id'=>1,'d_id'=>103,'available'=>1),
   array('m_id'=>1,'d_id'=>104,'available'=>0),
   array('m_id'=>1,'d_id'=>105,'available'=>0)
 );
```

My question is how I can update the table just with one query like this:

```
  $query = "UPDATE tbl_name SET available='".$data[0]['available']."'" WHERE conditon1";
```

I mean update table once instead of 5 query.

Answer (score 2):

In pure MySQL, you could use a `CASE` expression in the `UPDATE` to handle this:

```
UPDATE tbl_name
SET available = CASE WHEN d_id = 101 THEN 0
                     WHEN d_id = 102 THEN 1
                     WHEN d_id = 103 THEN 1
                     WHEN d_id = 104 THEN 0
                     WHEN d_id = 105 THEN 0 END
WHERE d_id IN (101, 102, 103, 104, 105)
```

If, on the other hand, you wanted to iterate over your array of arrays and then issue `UPDATE` statements, you could try the following:

```
foreach ($data as $entry) {
    $query = "UPDATE tbl_name SET available=".$entry['available']." WHERE d_id=".$entry['d_id'];
    // execute $query ...
}
```

Comment: Biegelesen. the array I received , is not static , it's possible to receive array with to records contains `m_id`, `d_id`, `available`. how can I handle it with foreach or other method

Comment: @korush I updated my answer to attempt to show how to use PHP's `foreach` loop to iterate over your array.

Comment: the problem is the query executed as the length of the array. I want just onec.

Comment: Then you would need to build a dynamic query.  This could be ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674737/mysql-update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-in-one-query). In a nutshell - you need to use either `CASE` conditional or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` construct.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data you have provided, where all rows reference the same columns, and always update the same column, you can create a simple `CASE` expression:

```
/* Mostly untested */

function update_array ($data)
{
  if (empty ($data))
    return NULL;

  if (count ($data) === 1) {

    /* Simple query for single update */

    $mi = $data[0]['m_id'];
    $di = $data[0]['d_id'];
    $av = $data[0]['available'];

    $sql = <<<_
UPDATE `tbl_name`
   SET `available` = $av
 WHERE `m_id`= $mi AND `d_id`= $di

_;

  } else {

    /* CASE WHEN query for multiple updates */

    $sql = "UPDATE `tbl_name`\n   SET `available` = \n           CASE ";

    foreach ($data as $d) {
      $mi = $d['m_id'];
      $di = $d['d_id'];
      $av = $d['available'];
      $sql .= "WHEN `m_id`=$mi AND `d_id`=$di THEN $av\n                ";
    }

    /* Never forget the ELSE clause! */

    $sql .= "ELSE `available`\n           END\n";
  }

  return $sql;
}
```

---

This test program:

```
$data = array(
  array('m_id'=>1, 'd_id'=>101, 'available'=>0),
  array('m_id'=>1, 'd_id'=>102, 'available'=>1),
  array('m_id'=>1, 'd_id'=>103, 'available'=>1),
  array('m_id'=>1, 'd_id'=>104, 'available'=>0),
  array('m_id'=>1, 'd_id'=>105, 'available'=>0)
);

echo update_array ($data);
```

outputs:

```sql
UPDATE `tbl_name`
   SET `available` =
           CASE WHEN `m_id`=1 AND `d_id`=101 THEN 0
                WHEN `m_id`=1 AND `d_id`=102 THEN 1
                WHEN `m_id`=1 AND `d_id`=103 THEN 1
                WHEN `m_id`=1 AND `d_id`=104 THEN 0
                WHEN `m_id`=1 AND `d_id`=105 THEN 0
                ELSE `available`
           END
```

---

Note:

- **Never** forget the `ELSE` clause in a `CASE WHEN` update. If you do, then all the non-matching rows will be overwritten with a blank value.
- This code blindly assumes that the data contains the expected indexes, and that the data is of the appropriate type.
- Some say that you should include a `WHERE` clause to limit the number of rows to be updated for performance reasons. I haven't seen any data to back this up, but if it is a concern, then a simple improvement *might* be to narrow it down using the `d_id` column. Just add the follow at the end of the `CASE WHEN` query:

  ```
  $ids = array_column ($data, 'd_id');
  $sql .= ' WHERE `d_id` IN (' . implode (', ', $ids) . ")\n";
  ```

  You still need the `ELSE` in the `CASE` expression because this `WHERE` clause is not guaranteed to exclude *all* the unwanted rows. Writing a complete `WHERE` clause will probably be much more complicated, depending on the exact nature of your data.