# How to insert data for one column for all the rows in single query in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+----------+
| id | phone_no   | join_date  | city       | blood_gp |
+----+------------+------------+------------+----------+
|  1 | 80077672xx | 1997-07-19 |  Delhi     | NULL     |
|  2 | 80077642xx | 1998-07-19 | New Delhi  | NULL     |
|  3 | 80477642xx | 1999-07-19 | Mumbai     | NULL     |
|  4 | 80077654xx | 1997-05-31 | Kolkata    | NULL     |
+----+------------+------------+------------+----------+
```

I want to enter all the blood groups at once . Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: can you show your expected result after `UPDATE`? is there a source for the data?

Comment: means ?? how ? from where ?

Comment: INSERT INTO yourtable
    (x,y,z)
VALUES
    (a1,a2,a3),
    (b1,b2,b3)

Comment: if you enter all value using single query then use this above

Comment: Duplicate question : @Varad Bhatnagar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674737/mysql-update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-in-one-query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL - UPDATE multiple rows with different values in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674737/mysql-update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-in-one-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use single query with select and update

```
UPDATE table1 , (SELECT * FROM table2 where 1) src 
  SET table1.blood_gp = src.filed2 where 1 ;
```

if you want to insert multiple row data using single query then use this code

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (x,y,z) VALUES (a1,a2,a3), (b1,b2,b3);
```

or if you want to update one column value all filed then use this code

```
update yourtable set blood_gp = 'yourvalue' where 1;
```

if any problem then inform me

Comment: @Varad Bhatnagar can you give me upvote? i did already so you can do that now

Answer (score 0):

Just make an update query without where clause.

```
update table set blood_gp = 'value'
```

That's generalize query.

Comment: What if i want to enter data which is not same for all rows ?

Comment: then query would be different.

Comment: I will have to use loop ?

Comment: Yes, It would be a better option. As there will be different values for each individual id.