# Updating multiply names in mysql

Tags: mysql

I've a big amont names for putting into mysql.

```
update tbl set value='value1' where code='123';
update tbl set value='value2' where code='124';
.... and an half milion lines
```

That takes too long time.
Is there some quicker posibility for updating names? Thank you

Comment: Where do the names come from? Are they already in the DB? Is it a CSV file?

Comment: use loop to update multiple records.

Comment: @GufranHasan: Absolutely not.

Comment: Already asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25674827/5026957

Comment: @harishsharma: With 500k values?

Comment: then you can group data where value is same but code is different, Or run queries in chunk,

Comment: I used the loop. In such case i have wait 2 days.

Comment: `update tbl set value='value1' where value!='value1' AND code='123';` use this, may be it will save your time, Don't use loop, You can create query inside loop with a logic that, if same value need to update in multiple code, then use mysql's IN, better than write multiple queries for them,

Comment: You haven't said how long it is actually taking or what you've done to try to resolve it. So let's go to first principles: First thing if your queries are taking too long (even if there's a lot of them) is to make sure the database is properly indexed. Do you have an index on the `code` field? If not, add one and you will see an orders-of-magnitude speed improvement.