# Change more than one row in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I need to change rows in my DB using 2 arrays, first stores names of rows which i need to change, second stores val. I've added the code , to understand what I want to do. Can i do it with 1 request to my DB

```
func update_1(){
    key := []string{"Name1", "Name2", "Name4"}
    val := []string{"1", "2", "4"}
    for i, _ := range key{
        _, err := db.Exec("UPDATE table SET val = $1 WHERE name = $2",val[i], key[i])
        if err != nil {
            errorLog.Println(err)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be possible with [SQL's case statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp), also please include your code as text

Comment: Edited, and included my code as text

Comment: I found this similar question about mysql, perhaps it answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674737/mysql-update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-in-one-query/25674827

Comment: if i use SQL's case statement, how can i use arrays?

Comment: you would need to generate the sql at runtime. Loop over each entry in your slice and add a case for it in your sql.

Comment: cant understand how can i run sql at runtime.

Comment: you can use a buffer and write to it in a loop, then execute the resulting string with `db.Exec()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the arrays into a Postgres query as parameters.  Then it is a simple `unnest()` and `update`:

```
update t
    set val = u.val
    from unnest(:ar_names, :ar_vals) u(name, val)
    where t.name = u.name;
```

Comment: db.Exec("update test set val = u.val from unnest($1::bigint[], $2::character varying[]) u(name, val) where test.name = u.name", pq.Array([]int{1, 3}), pq.Array([]string{"228", "228"})) my final request in golang