# Update multiple rows in a single query in a Supabase Database (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I looking to update multiple rows via a single query in Supabase. I'm struggling to find an example of how to do it online.

For this example here is how the data exists the database's 'food' table:

| id | title | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 10 |
| 2 | Banana | 8 |
| 3 | Mango | 4 |

What i would like to do is update the 3 **qty** fields in the single query (this code doesn't work but should give you an idea of what i am after).

```
const { data: item_data, error: item_error } = await supabase
   .from('food')
   .update({ qty: 11, }).eq('id', '1')
   .update({ qty: 9, }).eq('id', '2')
   .update({ qty: 6, }).eq('id', '3')
```

Comment: By using `case` like here [update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-in-one-query-in-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674737/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-in-one-query-in-mysql) but I'm not sure it's efficient and you can only do it with raw queries so you will lose your pretty query builder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with an `upsert()`:

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('food')
  .upsert([{id: 1, qty: 11}, {id: 2, qty: 9}, {id: 3, qty: 6}])
```

Additionally you can also do it with a SQL function as mentioned [here](https://github.com/supabase/postgrest-js/issues/174#issuecomment-819919742).